# Why parent print 2 times with fork in c

Tags: c, unix, fork

I'm learning fork() and I try to do a little program who print the child before the parent. It works but the parents print 2 times and I don't understand why.

Expected output :

```
4 5 6
1 2 3
```

Real output :

```
4 5 6
1 2 3
1 2 3
```

Here is my code :

```
int main (int argc, char** argv) {

    int childPid = fork();
    if (childPid == 0){
        printf("4 5 6\n");
    }

    wait(NULL);

    printf("1 2 3\n");
    exit(0);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The line `printf("1 2 3\n");` will be executed by both parent a child. The child will confront the    `wait(NULL);` line but will skip it since it has no childs and will print "1 2 3" and then it will exit. Meanwhile, the parent would receive the termination status of the child and will continue execution by printing "1 2 3" as well and exiting. In order to make it work properly, edit it accordingly:

```
int main (int argc, char** argv) {

    int childPid = fork();
    if (childPid == 0){
        printf("4 5 6\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    wait(NULL);

    printf("1 2 3\n");
    exit(0);

}
```